# Handling simple value rejects in a promise library

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

When the [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) module detects a non-`Error` reject, it reports `Warning: a promise was rejected with a non-error`.

So when we are writing a reusable promise library, how should we handle the situation when it is the client's code that throws simple values?

Simple `my-library` example:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

module.exports = function (cb) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        try {
            cb();
            resolve('some data');
        } catch (e) {

            // should we do this?
            reject(e);

            // or should we do this?
            // reject(e instanceof Error ? e : new Error(e));
        }
    });
};
```

A client that consumes it:

```
var lib = require('my-library');

lib(function () {
    throw 'Regular text';
})
    .catch(function (error) {
        // - should we expect exactly 'Regular text' here?
        // - or should it be wrapped into Error by the promise library?
    });
```

In the example above we are going to see the same `Warning: a promise was rejected with a non-error` again, which in this case is obviously the client's fault, but the problem is - it will be reported against the promise library that did the reject.

This brings a question of how a reusable library should handle such cases.

- **Option 1:** do nothing (just use `reject(e)`), let the client see the warning message `Warning: a promise was rejected with a non-error`.
- **Option 2:** verify if the error thrown is an instance of `Error` and if not - do `reject(new Error(e))`. This enables the client to throw and reject with simple values, which is probably bad.

I am looking for a general recommendation here.

Also consider that sometimes the client can be an old library that you are trying to wrap into promises.

Comment: This warning is all around `console.log(error.stack)`. If you care about it, then check the type of errors as early as possible.

Comment: @stdob-- I'm not sure what you mean by `If you care about it`. I am looking for a general recommendation, not asking about one specific case.

Comment: The [Bluebird documentation](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/docs/docs/warning-explanations.md#warning-a-promise-was-rejected-with-a-non-error) make the argument why always throwing an `Error` (ie _"Option 2"_) is recommendable.

Comment: @robertklep the problem with option 2 - it enables the client to throw values around, which is bad.

Comment: @vitaly-t yeah I see your point. Besides enabling the client to throw values around, they might also expect that what they throw ends up as-is in the `catch` handler. Although you, as developer of `my-library`, could argue that you want your library to adhere to best practices.

Comment: @robertklep I do want to follow the best practices, I just don't know what it would be from this perspective.

Comment: @vitaly-t there are arguments to be made for both cases. I _think_ that I would personally pass the thrown value as-is (and let Bluebird issue a warning), but always throw a proper `Error` instance in cases where my own code has to throw an exception.

Comment: @robertklep the more I think about it, the more I warm up to the same idea. Still, it would be nice if some experts were to share their views on this.

Comment: @vitaly-t could you add some more details about the library? Because it depends...

Comment: @GorgiKosev no, this is a question in general, not for a specific library.

Comment: @vitaly-t in that case the answer is "it depends on the library". It depends on what contract you want to present for the library which in turn depends on what contract makes sense for that particular use case.

Comment: To clarify-- the idea you and @robertklep are proposing, that is, let Bluebird issue a warning-- that means these warnings show up as spam on the javascript error console, right?  That's certainly a dealbreaker for me-- that would make the library I'm writing unusable for development, and it would look pretty shoddy to users who look to the error console, too.

Comment: @DonHatch I can't for the life of me reproduce the issue, so it may not be relevant anymore, but besides that: the issue happens when _your_ code throws non-errors. As long as you throw proper error instances, the warnings don't show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You should definitely and objectively wrap non-errors with errors.

Non errors are terrible for debugging, the bluebird warning is there because it is *very* hard to figure out where an error came from if it's a primitive. You can't attach properties to primitives and they have no stack traces.

Stack traces mean you don't have to guess where the errors come from - you know.

That said, bluebird already does this automatically with `promisify` and `promisifyAll` and consider using them. If you're doing this manually - just make sure you `throw` or `reject` things with stacks too.

Node in addition looks for the stack traces of your unhandled rejections - so rejecting with junk will not only give you useless information in Node but it might actually crash your program.

Comment: When you say `You should definitely`, it is confusing whether you refer to my promise library or to the client's code. The reason I asked the question is to weight cons and pros of the two options. And the second option implies that wrapping client-side errors in an `Error` will be enabling them to write invalid code with open-value throws and rejects. You didn't even touch on those considerations in your answer.

Comment: Why would you ever use the promise constructor in your library anyway? In any case if your library is actually a framework - definitely wrap, your users will thank you for it (for the reason above).

Comment: Does `promisify` in Bluebird wrap something like `throw 'Error'` into an `Error` object, or what kind check for the error does it do? It's more comlicated when you consider when the client is already a promise library that does something like `reject('ops!')`.

Comment: Yes it does, it wraps non-errors into `OperationalErrors`. If a promise library does `request("ops!")` it is indeed a problem and up to you to make an opinionated choice - bluebird doesn't wrap those with errors (since well, it doesn't really touch them at a clear surface point) - but we would if we could get away with it.

Comment: Ok, but in case of Bluebird, it both wraps the result and issues a warning. And when you consider a promise library that uses Bluebird, if it wraps such errors, they won't be reported by Bluebird (no warning will be issued), and then it is bad.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum A Promise and an Error should never be reliant on one-another. Not sure why you'd think that code which replaces a simple "Is this positive or negative" needs such obnoxious requirements. In nine of ten cases, it does not matter to the output where the code had rejected a promise. Just as I don't want to wrap every time I console.log in an Error object. This is utter absurdity.

Comment: @IzzyCooper rejections _do not_ replace positive or negatives. Rejections are exceptional paths that should not occur in a normal flow of your program. When you have an error - good luck finding out where it's from - if you're writing a library, get ready for some really annoyed users.

If you're using rejections for "regular true or false" flows all the time - you're going to end up with slow code that leaks a lot of memory - and Node will likely crash in a future version (today it will show a DeprecationWarning for not handling an error synchronously).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Not sure how you figure this. Considering you resolve all your Promises there shouldn't be memory leaks. Aside from that, Promises were created to nullify callback hell. You may simply reject a promise because a doesn't equal true, not sure why you think that needs to be wrapped in an Error. Do as you wish, but this is completely illogical. I should note that if there is a need to return an actual Error in a rejection, do so. I have a problem with forcing developers to use Promises in a non-practical manner.

Answer (score 1):

Error messages should be wrapped in error objects, but not *automatically*.

Automatic wrapping reduces the usefulness of stack traces. For example, lets say the client function is `f` and your library function is `g`:

```
function f(x) { throw 'Hello world' }
function g(f, x) { try { f(x); } catch (e) { throw new Error(e); } }

g(f, 1)
```

The client function and line numbers where the error originated will be completely missing from the stack:

```
Error: Hello world
    at g (repl:1:52)
    at repl:1:1
```

While if the client function creates the error object:

```
function f(x) { throw new Error('Hello world'); }
function g(f, x) { try{ f(x); } catch (e) { throw e; } }

g(f, 1)
```

we get a full stack trace:

```
Error: Hello world
    at f (repl:1:23)
    at g (repl:1:25)
    at repl:1:1
```

There is no way to recover the stack up to the point in your library, making it useless for users (they wont be able to debug their own code).

That said, this largely depends on what sort of library you're making and what sort of contract you would like it to present to the users. You should think very carefully before using user-passed callbacks, as they invert the normal chain of responsibility in the stack.

Promises make this easier because they un-invert the inversion: the library is called first to generate a promise, then that promise is passed a callback. As such, creating a new error together with the creation of the promise allows Bluebird to at least partially look into / augment the stack of the client code (the line that created the promise will be present in the stack). The warning is still there because its impossible to provide a complete stack.

Answer (score 0):

No, they simply want you to wrap your JSON error objects into something.

This is not freedom, it's dictature.

There's no point in wrapping simple JSON objects in bulky Error wrappers.

Don't listen to them.

Comment: Actually, there is a point, and a very valid one - to get the stack trace, so one can debug the code. Object `Error` provides stack tracing.

Comment: No, there is no point, and not a valid one - one doesn't need stack trace at all, just the plain Javascript object with error properties.

Comment: **TL;DR: A rejection doesn't always mean there is a bug in the code that requires a stacktrace. eg, a user provides garbage input.**. I agree with asdf. Yes, if an *unexpected* error occurs then we want the stackstrace but sometimes I want to reject if the given input was invalid and I know the rejection is not due to a bug in my code.  The rejection object I provide has all info needed determin why it was rejected. Grabbing the stacktrace is an unnecessary performance overhead.

Comment: I love how people are complaining about a feature they don't understand. I 100% stand behind warning on these, and I might even do this in the Node library since it has pretty solid consensus. The warning is there because we wasted hundreds of hours finding bugs. This is rediculous.  A rejection _does_ most certainly mean there is a possible bug in the code - if it's not an exceptional case _don't use rejections_. They are _slow_ for anything else.

Comment: Grabbing the stack trace is the least of your performance overhead with a rejection, this shows a fundamental misunderstanding of how your code runs with promises. Also, given we wrote a library you're using - you're welcome to use something else and spare calling us "fascists". There is also no such thing as a "JSON object" in JavaScript. Your answer can literally cost people thousands of hours of wasted time debugging - leaving the world worse just a little bit for it.

Comment: Benjamin Gruenbaum, you clearly don't have any clue on this matter and still try to behave like the smartest man in the world.

Comment: @asdfasdfads Benjamin is one of the core contributors to Bluebird, he's also a Node core collaborator, if there's anyone who has a clue on this matter, it's him.